# How to "select all" in LINQ query with nullable column

Tags: c#, linq

This takes a little bit of setup to explain. I know "nulls are bad" in a database and I am experiencing why that can be so, but I have no choice about the way the business uses the data source. The data source has nulls in the dataset and I have to work with it as-is. (Hopefully this addresses the anticipated "Well, your dataset shouldn't have nulls..." or "Why don't you just remove the nulls...?")

Suppose I have sample set like this, where "NULL" is an actual null:

> ```
> Campus | Name      | Relationship
> ---------------------------------
> A      | Bob       |  Relationship 1
> B      | Bill      |  NULL
> B      | Carol     |  Relationship 2
> C      | Sally     |  Relationship 1
> ```

Now suppose I am using an option list to filter the results by a distinct list of the values in the `Relationship` column:

- All (meaning show all records)
- NULL
- Relationship 1
- Relationship 2

If I didn't have the "All" option, it would be simple enough:

```
private IEnumerable<RwsBasePhonesAndAddress> PopulateQuery(string SelectedCampus, 
    string SelectedRelationship)
{
    IEnumerable<RwsBasePhonesAndAddress> query =
        db.RwsBasePhonesAndAddresses.Where(m => m.Campus == SelectedCampus);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedRelationship))
        query = query.Where(m => m.Relationship == SelectedRelationship);
    else
        query = query.Where(m => m.Relationship == null);

    query = query.OrderBy(m => m.StudentName).AsEnumerable();
    return query;
}
```

I have verified that the code as written returns results matching the "SelectedRelationship" parameter, including "NULL" records when "NULL" is chosen as a filter.

It's the inclusion of the "All" in the option list that makes this difficult. If the "Relationship" column had no nulls, I could use a null `SelectedRelationship` parameter as the "do not filter by 'SelectedRelationship'" option.

Is there some way that I can use a "do not filter" option into the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure that I understood the question. From what I understood to the code above you are missing the part that if you get an "All" value then not to filter out anything. Right? If so:

```
private IEnumerable<RwsBasePhonesAndAddress> PopulateQuery(string SelectedCampus, 
    string SelectedRelationship)
{
    IEnumerable<RwsBasePhonesAndAddress> query =
        db.RwsBasePhonesAndAddresses.Where(m => m.Campus == SelectedCampus);

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedRelationship))
        query = query.Where(m => m.Relationship == null);
    else if (SelectedRelationship != "All")
        query = query.Where(m => m.Relationship == SelectedRelationship);

    query = query.OrderBy(m => m.StudentName).AsEnumerable();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Now it looks obvious, now that I'm looking at it. I just had to see if from another angle.